# Customizing Databind Json serialization format of MonetaryAmount JSR354 / moneta

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jsr354

I'm trying to Json Serialize a POJO with MonetaryAmount field as a string, but the resulting output does not follow the prescribed shape format.

```
// org.javamoney:moneta:1.1 
// com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "CBNOT_CHARGEBACK_AMOUNT"
})
public class TestMonetaryAmountJsonSerialization {
        @JsonProperty("CBNOT_CHARGEBACK_AMOUNT")
        @NotNull
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "¤#,##0.00", locale = "en_US")
        private final MonetaryAmount chargebackAmount = Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory().setCurrency("USD").setNumber(12.50).create();

        private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        @Test
        public void testThis() throws JsonProcessingException{
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
            System.out.println(json);
            Assert.assertEquals("{\"CBNOT_CHARGEBACK_AMOUNT\":\"¤12.50\"}",json);
        }

}

OUTPUT: {"CBNOT_CHARGEBACK_AMOUNT":{"currency":{"context":{"empty":false,"providerName":"java.util.Currency"},"defaultFractionDigits":2,"currencyCode":"USD","numericCode":840},"number":12.5,"factory":{"defaultMonetaryContext":{"precision":0,"fixedScale":false,"amountType":"org.javamoney.moneta.Money","maxScale":63,"empty":false,"providerName":null},"maxNumber":null,"minNumber":null,"amountType":"org.javamoney.moneta.Money","maximalMonetaryContext":{"precision":0,"fixedScale":false,"amountType":"org.javamoney.moneta.Money","maxScale":-1,"empty":false,"providerName":null}},"context":{"precision":0,"fixedScale":false,"amountType":"org.javamoney.moneta.Money","maxScale":63,"empty":false,"providerName":null},"numberStripped":12.5,"zero":false,"negative":false,"negativeOrZero":false,"positive":true,"positiveOrZero":true}}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?  I threw the kitchen sink in this code here, only for illustrative purposes and compact presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JsonFormat](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) is an annotation used in several (de)serializers defined by Jackson (e.g. [DateTimeSerializerBase](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/DateTimeSerializerBase.java#L56), [NumberSerializers.Base](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/NumberSerializers.java#L85) and some other, full list [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html)), it's not a general purpose mechanism turning any object into a string:

> Unlike most other Jackson annotations, annotation does not have
>   specific universal interpretation: instead, effect depends on datatype
>   of property being annotated (or more specifically, deserializer and
>   serializer being used).

Specifying it won't have any effect unless you create a custom serializer for `MonetaryAmount` or use one that makes use of this annotation (and also its `pattern` property), but if you create a custom serializer, chances are you won't need that level of flexibility as to specify different patterns for different fields and could just use a fixed [MonetaryAmountFormat](https://javamoney.github.io/apidocs/javax/money/format/MonetaryAmountFormat.html) or build the necessary string from the `MonetaryAmount` object otherwise.

For example

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "CBNOT_CHARGEBACK_AMOUNT"
})
public class TestMonetaryAmountJsonSerialization {
    @JsonProperty("CBNOT_CHARGEBACK_AMOUNT")
    @NotNull
    private final MonetaryAmount chargebackAmount = Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory().setCurrency("USD").setNumber(12.50).create();

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    static {
        SimpleModule monetaryModule = new SimpleModule();
        monetaryModule.addSerializer(MonetaryAmount.class, new MonetaryAmountSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(monetaryModule);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThis() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        System.out.println(json);
        Assert.assertEquals("{\"CBNOT_CHARGEBACK_AMOUNT\":\"$12.50\"}", json);
    }

    public static class MonetaryAmountSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MonetaryAmount> {
        public void serialize(MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount,
                              JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                              SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            MonetaryAmountDecimalFormatBuilder
                    .of("¤#,##0.00").withCurrencyUnit(monetaryAmount.getCurrency()).build()
                    .print(sb, monetaryAmount);
            jsonGenerator.writeString(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```